# Avoiding buffer length checks before buffer access in C++

Tags: c++

I have a `char*` buffer which we need to decode into a db. The buffer is such that if not null, it's very big and contains integers and strings.

The buffer will contain contents like a 4-byte integer length followed by that an ASCII string that many characters long. Then it's followed by another 4-byte length and a string of that length, and so on until we reach the end.

Most of the time the buffer is valid but sometimes I see that the buffer is corrupted and I get a SEGV. I get a SEGV since the length resulted in reading more bytes than the rest of the buffer length.

I *do not* want to put checks everywhere for the remaining buffer length before decoding. The buffer fields are 200 in number. What check can I provide here which can help me solve this problem without the overhead of extra `if` checks?

Comment: You want to be able to do the checks without paying the overhead of the checks. Hmmm...

Comment: Putting in the checks are likely work on your part, but are likely to add very little overhead to the overall process.  And you're lucky when you get a SEGV to at least stop you from processing corrupted data.  If you don't read very far past the end of the buffer, you may not get a SEGV since you may be accessing other parts of this same program's memory which won't generate a SEGV, but which will contain unexpected data.

Comment: Rereading your question, it sounds like you are envisioning adding 200 if statements to your code to deal with this.   You don't show any code, which is somewhat expected when asking a questions tagged with C++, but I suspect that you need to change your code such that you are calling a function something like  getNextField() each time you need another block of data from the buffer.   That function can then have a check each time, that you only need to code once.   Again, the impact on performance is likely not even measurable if done properly.

Comment: You could consider writing a macro that performs the check but keeps the code in a simple syntax

Comment: I am using macro to perform this repeated operation and i feel these many if checks will have an impact on performance . I thought there is some easy available solution for bound checks at source ptr  which will not hamper my performance much .

Comment: So you occasionally read off the end of the buffer because one of the field length prefixes has an incorrect value in them? I'm assuming you have access to the total buffer length separately? If so, you should be able to validate the contents by reading every length prefix, using that to jump to the next length prefix and accumulating them as you go. That doesn't sound like a very expensive operation to me. Anyway, not wanting to do something because you *think* it might affect performance is a weak argument.

Comment: Any easily available / built-in solution would still be doing the same "if" operations that you would, so from a performance perspective it would be just as fast/slow as doing the checking explicitly in your own code.  Just because you didn't write the code wouldn't mean it executes for free.  (Keep in mind, however, that modern CPUs have pretty good branch prediction optimizations, so the presence of the if statements is unlikely to slow execution down anywhere near as much as you might think -- try it for yourself, write a benchmark test and run it with and then without the "if" statements!)

Comment: It's pretty much horrible practice and is blatantly negligent to knowingly write code with buffer overflow vulnerabilities. Perhaps you should consider another language.

Comment: You're dealing with a database. The overhead of doing that is at least three orders of magnitude more than the overhead of checking your lengths. The more interesting question here is *why* is your data corrupt? That's what you should be devoting your time to,